# Formatting - how to get better outputs

Tags: mapinfo

I am always after improving my mapinfo outputs and I wondered what tips you have to improve the general look of an output.

I suppose this comes from having a good selection of both raster or vector layers.

I have the OS layers. Any tips?

Comment: It's hard to suggest improvements when we don't know the what is being improved upon.  You will at least have to show some examples.

Comment: Try to ask a specific question rather than asking for tips which is too broad for focussed Q&A.

Answer (score 2):

A few things spring to mind (not in any particular order)...

1. When using raster backgrounds make sure that you are using one at
   an appropriate scale and detail for the zoom level your output will
   be
2. Spend some time sorting out your labels (if you're using any).
   MapInfo isn't the best when it comes to labeling so a bit of time
   spent dragging labels around can make a big difference
3. Don't clutter the map, only show data that is necessary to what
   you are trying to represent.
4. Use thematics where you can. Thematics are a great way of
   representing attribute information without resorting to labels and
   can quickly give an end user the 'big picture'
5. Learn your way around the Layout editor. It's critical that you
   know what you're doing here particularly when it comes to outputting
   maps to scale.

It really depends on what your outputs are for and ultimately what you are trying to get across but the above should apply to most applications.